# Connection string is not valid in reporting services SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting following error every time I try to register new user in Reporting Services Form Authentication. I don't know how to get away from it. I am following the steps from [here](https://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com).

Error message is:

> An error occurred while attempting to add the account. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Any solution?

Comment: Fix your connection string!

Comment: Show us your connection string

Comment: SqlConnection(
            "Server=SERVERNAME\\MSSQLSERVER;" +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
            "database=UserAccounts").

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is not correct. Test it in another tool other than your program if you have doubt. First thing to check is if the server is actually accessible as the message states `The server was not found or was not accessible`.

Comment: The fact is that I was not allowed to connect to reporting service via SSMS with either Window Authentication or Form Authentication. My scale out deployment in Report Configuration Manager is not joined to any server.

Comment: Maybe your network admin guys should fix this for  you.

Comment: I have tested connection using udl and succeed.t is just so easy I have to create a new report server database and the server is joined under scale-out deployment.